# What is the default order of result set from Get-ChildItem command in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What is the default order of result set from Get-ChildItem command in powershell?
Is there a order at all or is it just random and would give the results in a different order every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
First folders in alphanumeric order (first numbers as [char]).
Then files in alphanumeric order (first numbers as [char]).
```

Comment: this is wrong. Do you have a quote for this?

Answer (score 14):

There is no guaranteed default sort order. [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/Get-ChildItem) doesn't state one.

The implementation in `FileSystemProvider` ends up calling [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx). The documentation for that states

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort
> method if a specific sort order is required.

The underlying API calls are `Find­First­File` and `FindNextFile`. Raymond Chen [explains here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190212233555/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140304-00/?p=1603) that in practice the file system driver may observe some ordering rules but this should not be relied upon.

Comment: same as `dir` which also uses `Find­First­File` and `FindNextFile`: [What order does the DIR command arrange files if no sort order is specified?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140304-00/?p=1603), [Default file order of “dir” command in Windows console](https://superuser.com/q/481570/241386)

Answer (score 4):

Sorting by default doesn't work for me. I get:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        2015-10-12     10:51            tools
d----        2015-10-12     10:58            cfg
d----        2015-10-12     10:51            res
d----        2015-10-12     10:50            brand
d----        2015-10-12     10:51            lib
```

I don't recall changing sort order. I'm on Windows 7 SP1. If I need sorted result I have to do `ls | sort`.

Comment: it's because `Get-ChildItem` doesn't sort its items, as said above