# Sorting/re-arranging files by US/UK LastWriteTime

Tags: date, powershell

I have a directory of files with the similar filenames in Windows, and the Date Modified are in UK date format `dd/mm/yyyy`, and all I need to do is select the "-last 1" based on the `dd` and `mm`. In this case, it's a file with a Windows Date Modified date of "07/12/16" or "7th Dec 2016". There is also another file in the same directory with a UK date "01/12/16", or "1st Dec 2016" for reference. There are lots of other files there too.

However, when running `gci "<path>" | Select -last 1` on the directory, it returns "12/01/16" instead of "12/07/16", so it's assuming the first part of the date is in US (mm) and sorting by that. Selecting the -first 1 doesn't help as this will select the earliest file in August, "16/08/2016" which is interpreted as "16/08/16".

How can I manipulate the `LastWriteTime` to read out in the format I want it to be in? I have tried

```
gci "\\my-Path\.csv" | Select Name, {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")}
```

but this brings back something weird ("07/38/2016")

Comment: `mm` is minutes, `MM` is months. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). In addition, `Get-ChildItem` [doesn't seem to have](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40619704) any specific sort order, so explicit sorting is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just want to *pipe* the `Get-ChildItem` result to the `Sort-Object` cmdlet using the `LastWriteTime` property:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\my-Path\.csv" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -first 1
```